# Declared variables not colored while using vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Declared variables happened to not be colored when I'm coding. When a friend showed me a screenshot of their code (working on the same project) I noticed that their variables were colored and was also using vscode.

I tried changing to dark+ (previously used dark high contrast). Also tried reinstalling vs code but nothing changed.

p.s

Also tried their color theme but the variables still isn't colored.

Friend's screen shot:
[image]

Mine:
[image]

Comment: try both using the same theme

Comment: I already did, I tried theirs and variables still didn't get colored on mine

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using "Dark (Visual Studio)" theme try "Dark+ (default dark)"